# Python library to plot regression residuals against each predictor and fitted values

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression, linear-regression

In R, when doing linear modeling I often use the `residualPlots` method from the `cars` library to plot my model residuals against my fitted values and against each numeric/applicable regressor.  This is done all at once with a single function call. For example,

[image]

**Is there an equivalent library in Python that plots residuals against fitted values and against my predictors, all at once?**

I'm aware I can plot small multiples in matplotlib using a loop, I'm looking for something that does it in one go.   I know `statsmodels.graphics.plot_partregress` does this for partial regression plots, but I haven't been able to find its equivalent just for straight residuals.  Integration with statsmodels, and ability to compute other residuals (externally studentized) as part of plotting a big bonus.